# When using jQuery .each(), is it possible to use a non-anonymous function?

Tags: jquery, refactoring, each

I have this code block I find particularly long and hard to udnerstood : the call stack is full of implicit functions and paramters implicitely added to it. in other words, i would like to clarify my code by separating the function called in the each from the each itself.

Look that example :

```
$(xml).find('group').each(function () {
    var groupName = $(this).attr('name');
    // There is here around 100 lines of codes I would like to split in 
    // at least five functions, And I'm sure it is possible to use named functions
    // instead of implicit ones, no ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing function reference

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/rDrAJ/)**

```
$(xml).find('group').each(myfun);

function myfun(i, item)
{
    alert(item.id);
}
```

Comment: Note that the callback function accepts indexInArray and valueOfElement arguments. The latter can be used instead of $(this)

Comment: Thanks for note, check my answer I added a demo.

Answer (score 3):

You could also just do:

```
$(xml).find('group').each(function(){
    yourFunction();
});
```

Comment: +1.  Perfectly clean abstraction introduced exactly where needed.

Comment: @CarlManaster I beg you pardon ? There is absolutely no introduced abstraction here ... unless `yourFunction` uses a different set of parameters from the anonymous function one, in which case one can as well de-anonymise function and name it.

Comment: @Riduidel, the code has been extracted into its own named function.  That cleanly separates the call from the messy details of what goes on inside, so this block becomes comprehensible.  Further changes may be made to the extracted block to make it more readable, but this block won't be affected; it's already been made clean through that one, simple, step of abstraction: Extract Method.

Comment: Doing it this way would mean that your function isn't forced to take an argument that shouldn't really be relevant to the function.  Ideally, you'd do something like:
    $(xml).find('group').each(function(idx,item){
        yourFunction(item);
    });