# named function as parameter in .each() method jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you want a named (so not an anonymous) function to be the paramter of the each .each() method, do you have to write the function name with or without parantheses? So like this

```
$('li').each(functioName())
```

or like this

```
$('li').each(functioName)
```

Comment: Have you tried these yourself? What works, what doesn't? Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086769/when-using-jquery-each-is-it-possible-to-use-a-non-anonymous-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using jQuery .each(), is it possible to use a non-anonymous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086769/when-using-jquery-each-is-it-possible-to-use-a-non-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without anonymous function you have to use the second method without parantheses.

```
$('li').each(functioName)
```

Ensure the method correctly uses the parameters index and element.

Comment: Thanks for the the answer, and in order to use the element and index function you would have to do simething like this right?       function functionName(index, element){};

Answer (score 0):

`without`

with () actually invokes it.

Answer (score 0):

Without parentheses

the difference is when you pass a function with a parentheses you actually pass the function returned function not the function it self.

```
   function x(someFunction){
       console.log(typeof someFunction)
   }

   function a (){
       return 1;
   }

   x(a); // function
   x(a()); // 1
```

Note that `a` !== `a()`

[CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgQZzg?editors=0012)